# Storing avatar path in MySQL DB and Laravel Socialite - Login with Facebook

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Currently I'm implementing Login with Facebook function in my Laravel 8 project.

After successful login, Socialite returns Facebook user object, with its attributes e.g. token, id, nickname, email and avatar.

Actually, the avatar path is incorrect, because it's a placeholder image. However, if I append additional access_token param to the avatar URL I manage to access the correct avatar (according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67005757)

My question is: is it correct to save in my MySQL DB user avatar url with access_token? Is this access token public and is this solution safe (authenticated users in my application may see another user avatar URL which contains this access_token).

Comment: Facebook recently changed the requirements, regarding the availability of the profile picture. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#requirements, you might not need to pass an access token after all, once your application is actually active and you have the Data Use Checkup completed.

Comment: _“is it correct to save in my MySQL DB user avatar url with access_token?”_ - No. Apart from the issue of potentially exposing a user’s access token to other people, these image URLs aren’t valid forever to begin with, quote from the documentation mentioned in previous comment: _“Profile picture URLs returned by this edge will expire.”_